# Pass Previous month value as parameter to ssrs

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS. I have created some reports, Which take two parameters, Id and Date. Client wants to see the previous month data in one report. And we are passing the parameter through SSIS Package.
My query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Id= @Id AND Period =@Period.
```

The parameters value SSIS Package pass, i have to show the previous month. e.g. if ssis package passed 2020-07-01 so i have to show the data for 2020-06-01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select * from Table1
where Id = @Id
    and Period between
            dateAdd(mm, -1, dateAdd(mm, dateDiff(mm, 0, @Period), 0)) -- 1st day of prev month
        and dateAdd(dd, -1, dateAdd(mm, dateDiff(mm, 0, @Period), 0)) -- last day of prev month
```

Comment: Ok, mark the question as solved would be appreciated